# Balancing an equation

Tags: equilibrium

so I might be just way to tired for this, but I somehow have a stupid mistake here when trying to balance an equation.

$$Zn(s)+MnO_2(s)+NH_4^{+}(aq)=Zn^{2+}(q)+Mn_2O_3(s)+NH_3(aq)+H_2O(l)\tag{1}$$

Here's what I do:

$$A\cdot Zn(s)+B\cdot MnO_2(s)+C\cdot NH_4^{+}(aq)=D\cdot Zn^{2+}(q)+E\cdot Mn_2O_3(s)+F\cdot NH_3(aq)+G\cdot H_2O(l)\tag{2}$$

We get

$Z_n: \quad A=D$

$Mn:\quad B=2E$

$O:\quad 2B=3E+G$

$N:\quad C=F$

$H:\quad 4C=3F+2G$

$z:\quad  C=2D$

We see that

$$Z_n \ \& \ N \ \& \ z: \quad A=D=\frac{1}{2}C=\frac{1}{2}F\tag{3}$$
and
$$O \ \& \ Mn:\quad 4E=3E+G \quad \Rightarrow \quad E=G\tag{4}$$
so it follows
$$Mn:\quad B=2E=2G\tag{5}$$
we also see
$$N \ \& \ H: \quad 4F=3F+2G \quad \Rightarrow \quad F=2G\tag{6}$$
so we get the relationship:
$$A=D=\frac{1}{2}C=\frac{1}{2}F=G=E=frac{1}{2}B\tag{7}$$
in correct order:
$$A=\frac{1}{2}B=\frac{1}{2}C=D=E=\frac{1}{2}F=G\tag{8}$$

Now the actual solution is:
$$Zn(s)+2MnO_2(s)+2NH_4^{+}(aq)=Zn^{2+}(q)+Mn_2O_3(s)+2NH_3(aq)+H_2O(l) \tag{9}$$

so I should have gotten:

$$A=2B=2C=D=E=2F=G\tag{8}$$

I don't see what's wrong. :/

Comment: No, your solution is right because $A = 1$ and $B = 2$, not the other way around. However, you tried to solve a seven variable system of equations without the help of linear algebra, which just made the process more error prone. This problem is even easier if you know about oxidation states.

Comment: I could have made n matrix and solved that, sure. But in general it's not worht the effort for my basic chemistry here. I also just noticed that if I choose $A=1$ then $1=0.5B \Rightarrow B=2$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is right, and the answer given is the correct answer. What you have written in equation 8 is incorrect. The numbers you have multiplied in each variable should actually be in the denominator, since they are the ratios.